# Get string content of parent node that is before child

Tags: java, xml, dom

Using Java, I am trying to figure how to retrieve the string of a parent node, up to the beginning of the child node:

```
<para>This is a paragraph with a child <dmRef><dmRefIdent><dmCode att="somevalue"/></dmRefIdent></dmRef> and then some more text.</para>
```

I would like to analyze the text prior to the beginning of .

I have retrieved the complete string using `node.getParent.getTextContent()` where `node` is the `<dmRef>` element, but am looking for a way to get only the text prior to the `<dmRef>` element (**This is a paragraph with a child**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath:

Given that you execute the XPath in the context of the `para` element node:

Select the first `dmRef` element:

`dmRef[1]`

Get the preceding sibling text nodes:

`dmRef[1]/preceding-sibling::text()`

Executing the XPath will return a node list. You will have to iterate it and get the text content from each node. If you are sure that here is only a single text node you can cast ist into a string in XPath:

```
string(dmRef[1]/preceding-sibling::text())
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I overlooked XPath. I used an XPath on the Node of the `<dmRef>` looking for the first preceding text() node:

`preceding-sibling::text()[1]`

This is returning exactly what I need, thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.